# The Parameter's precision of OpenGL function glColor4d

Tags: opengl

I have problems with glcolor4d(). Since the data size is very large and I used
 `glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glBlendEquationSeparate(GL_FUNC_ADD, GL_FUNC_ADD);` 
to meet my needs, I set the the parameter with 
`glColor4d(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.04)`
 (the Parameters as small as possible). Once the alpha value and RGB parameters are lower than some values like 0.04, the data coundn't be display on the window.
So is there any limitations about the function precision? And how can I resovle this problem to set the parameter as small as possible? Hoping your reply.

Comment: If we're talking about an 8-bit framebuffer, 0.05 * 0.04 = 0.002, which is 1/500, but the smallest non-zero value can be represented in 8 bits is 1/255 ≈ 0.00392.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much all of the `d` versions of the vertex attribute functions are utterly useless.

Your framebuffer does not have double-precision floats. The best you can do is use single-precision floats, but that requires using single-precision floats, which is not the default. So you need to use an FBO to render to such an image, which you probably aren't doing. The general default pixel format you'll get is 8-bits-per-pixel.

And that's ignoring whether the fixed-function pipeline will operate on floating-point values. It is just as likely to turn them into 8-bits-per-pixel values (since that's what colors are defined to be in the FFP).

If you want higher precision for your colors, then you need to use shaders.